# WiX burn Upgrade shows uninstall UI at the end

Tags: wix, upgrade, bootstrapper, burn

I am trying to create a custom UI for WiX and Burn.
I'm almost done except one thing. In the end of installation which is upgrading(for exaple 1.0.0 to 1.1.0) uninstall for the previous version starts and the UI of it shows.
My question is how should I handle this so the user doesn't see uninstall UI in the end.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? Experiencing the same issue here

Answer (score 8):

When performing an upgrade of a Burn-based installer, the process will upgrade each of the MSIs bundled inside the installer, then it will *uninstall* the previous version's bundle using the commandline arguments `-uninstall -quiet -burn.related.upgrade -burn.embedded` (and a bunch of other stuff). If you're writing a your custom UI in .NET, that will present itself in the WiX `BootstrapperApplication` base class with these property values:

- `Command.Action` property as `LaunchAction.Uninstall`
- `Command.Display` property of `None` or `Embedded`

When the `Command.Display` is set to `None` or `Embedded`, your custom UI will need to hide itself (ie: don't display a UI). My guess is that you're currently not hiding the UI in this scenario, which is why it's displaying during the upgrade.

Comment: Look at BOOTSTRAPPER_RELATION_TYPE for BOOTSTRAPPER_RELATION_UPGRADE. Relying on BOOTSTRAPPER_DISPLAY for BOOTSTRAPPER_DISPLAY_EMBEDDED will give you the wrong information when a bundle is run as embedded without being upgraded.