# WiX Custom Bootstrapper Application Installer Upgrade

Tags: wix, burn, wix3

I created a setup using custom BA using WiX 3.11. Created two different version setup for Upgrade. Upgrade operations are working fine. Installer, uninstalled the older version setup and installed current version setup. But during upgrade, setup launches the older version setup Bootstrapper UI. I need to do the silent upgrade (on upgrade older version will be uninstalled silently). Any suggestions on this?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WiX burn Upgrade shows uninstall UI at the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30117285/wix-burn-upgrade-shows-uninstall-ui-at-the-end)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at my answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30271079/682840

The key is to write the version being *uninstalled* to detect that it's being uninstalled in silent mode and to not show a UI.

The problem, though, is that if you've already shipped the previous version, you can't change it now, so uninstalling it will still show the UI.  Going forward, new versions (once you've incorporated this change) will stop showing the UI.